# How to add Picasso request creator programmatically

Tags: android, picasso

Recently I try to use Picasso library to load images in Android. As far as I know, a standard loading may look like:

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
.load(source)
.placeholder(drawable_placeholder)
.resize(width, height)
.centerInside()
.into(imageView)
```

However, to customize loading accroding to some paramters (ex: a boolean usePlaceholder for placeholder or noPlaceholder), I can only use:

```
if (usePlaceholder) {
    Picasso.with(mContext)
    .load(source)
    .placeholder(drawable_placeholder)
    .resize(width, height)
    .centerInside()
    .into(imageView)
} else {
    Picasso.with(mContext)
    .load(source)        
    .resize(width, height)
    .centerInside()
    .into(imageView)
}
```

As shown above, the codes in if/else are almost the same. Is there any better way to add/remove some requestCreators programmatically? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
RequestCreator requestCreator = Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(source)
                .resize(width, height)
                .centerInside();

if (usePlaceholder) {
requestCreator = requestCreator.placeholder(drawable_placeholder);
}
requestCreator.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do at best:

```
RequestCreator rc = Picasso.with(mContext)
    .load(source)
    .resize(width, height)
    .centerInside();

if(usePlaceholder)
     rc = rc.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder);

rc.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a static method to return the Picasso `RequestCreator` in a class called `PicassoCreator` for instance, like

```
class PicassoCreator {
    public static RequestCreator create(Context context, boolean isPlaceholder, String source) {
        RequestCreator creator = Picasso.with(context)
                .load(source);
        if (isPlaceholder) {
            creator.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder);
        }
        return creator;
    }
}
```

and add whatever other `creator.centerInside()` or `creator.fit()` or `creator.resize(width,height)` before returning the creator, as well as changing the `source` parameter to be whatever you have (my example could be a URL). Then use it in your code like

```
PicassoCreator.create(getContext(),true, "https://example.com/image.jpeg")
    .into(view);
```